# Как выровнять меню?

Tags: html, menu

Как выровнять меню по высоте (вертикально)

```css
.header {
 background: #ccc;
 width: 100%;
 height: 90px;
 position: absolute;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c6cfe4, #ecf1fd);
}
.header-menu {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 960px;
 height: 90px;
 position: relative;
 
}
.logo-text {
 display: block;

}
.text-one {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 45pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: linear-gradient(#6972b5, #3b589c);
 -webkit-background-clip: text; 
 color: transparent;
 box-shadow: 1px #fff:
}
.text-two {
 font-family: Arial; 

 color: #3b589c;
}

ul.header-blog li{
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 36px;
 font-size: 13pt;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #2f57a1; 
}
.header-blog {
 float: right;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Home</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="header-menu">
   <div class="logo-text">
    <p class="text-one">Corporatix</p>
    <p class="text-two">Corporate Business PSD Template</p>
   </div>
   <ul class="header-blog">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Testimonial </li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно что и как нужно выровнять, может, как направление, так :

```css
.header {
 background: #ccc;
 width: 100%;
 height: 90px;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c6cfe4, #ecf1fd);
}

.logo-text {
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 30%;
 height: 90px;
}
.text-one {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 45pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: linear-gradient(#6972b5, #3b589c);
 -webkit-background-clip: text; 
 color: transparent;
 box-shadow: 1px #fff:
}
.text-two {
 font-family: Arial; 
 color: #3b589c;
}

.menu {
 float: left;
    width: 69%;
 height: 90px;
}

.header-blog {
     word-spacing: 12pt;
}

.header-blog li{
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 13pt;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #2f57a1; 
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="header">

   <div class="logo-text">
       
    <span class="text-one">Corporatix</span><br><span class="text-two">Corporate Business PSD Template</span>
                
   </div>
   <div class="menu">
       
     <ul class="header-blog">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Testimonial </li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
     </ul>
        
      </div>

 </div>
</body>
```